# What methods are available for using non-fixed values in Storyboard Animations?

Tags: .net, wpf, storyboard

As you may know, the `Animation.To` and `Animation.From` properties must be strictly literal values, or marked up resources using the `{StaticResource}` extension, else a rather draconian `InvalidOperationException` shall appear: `Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads.`

Certain techniques, including (but not limited to) `ResourceDictionary` swapping, repurposing of unused element properties in a `ControlTemplate` and/or attached properties for styling seem to stand in the way of this limitation.

Never minding the (probably quite understandable) reason behind this limitation, please share your experience with storyboarding animations which don't have immutable `To` and `From` values.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases only providing a `To` or `By` value solves the problem because the animation will then be relative to the current value.

Comment: That's really great information. Using only `To` without `From` reduces the code and improves readability IMO.